# Bootstrap navbar collpase button works on PC but not laptop or phone

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

The bootstrap navbar collapse button only works on my PC and not my laptop or phone. My PC is running windows 7, my laptop is running windows 10, and I have an android phone. They're all updated as far as I know and they are all using chrome. I have been doing all the coding on codepen.

Link to codepen: https://codepen.io/mounti/pen/grBQBj

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarbutton">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar Practice</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarbutton">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Second</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Third</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a bad link in your bootstrap js CDN :

```
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

use this link :

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Goodness. Thank you so much!